# Cron watchdog for a python script

Tags: cron, pgrep

I have a python script that should be restarted automatically every time it fails.

I've trying to use for this purpose cron with the following setting:

```
*/2 * * * * pgrep -f handler.py || /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/python3.6 /root/projects/myproject1/handler.py &
```

Although, if I run this command directly in cli it starts well, but it doesn't work in cron.

Syslog shows Cron's attempts to run the command without any errors:

```
CRON[10810]: (root) CMD (pgrep -f handler.py || /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/python3.6 /root/projects/myproject1/handler.py &)
```

Comment: You have given full path for all commands but pgrep and handler.py. Is that a problem?

Comment: @StephenBoston unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to run the script as a [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) service or under [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) or similar process control system.

EDIT:

Just to clarify the reason. You do not have to invent wheel. Both systemd and supervisor does exactly what You need.

Comment: Supervisor is what I've been looking for. Thank you!